# Java annotation using Pyjnius

Tags: android-webview, kivy, pyjnius

I copied [this code to use android native WebView](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Android-native-embedded-browser) in my Kivy application. Works perfectly :)

Now, I would like to bind my JavaScript with my Kivy application.
I've read through [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript):

```
...
/** Show a toast from the web page */
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast) {
...
```

How can I create a PyJnius class that has `@JavascriptInterface` annotation?

Thanks!